# Convert .lib project to exe one

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have simple *.lib project that I would like convert to console executable one.

After setting property in `General->Configuration` Type to `Application(.exe)` and compile I got error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: You could always just keep the library as a library and create a new console project that *uses* that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every C++ program requires a **main** function:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Your static library probably does not have one.